# Generating HTML Forms With Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

My app uses javascript to generate all the HTML for my website. The index.html basically just contains

```
<div id="menu"></div><div id="content/><div id="content2/>
```

And the javascript replaces the divs. I find myself doing a lot of repetitive tasks when I need to create a form.

```
var html = "<form id="form1"> ... </form>";
```

Is there a good framework to generate HTML forms so that you could do something like

```
generateForm(<formId>, [{name: "field1", type: button}, {name: "field2", type: input}]);
```

Or something similar?

Comment: So when I disable javascript I get a blank page from your website. Great idea. Btw google would then also see nothing

Comment: It's an internal app. It's purely an interface for a java app and it's nice to not have reloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify the generation by using a framework like MooTools, jQuery, etc...

To generate a form you would have something like this (in *[MooTools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element)*):

```
var form = new Element('form', { 'id' : 'myFormId', 'class' : 'myFormClass', ... });
var btn = new Element('input', { 'type' : 'button' , ... })
form.inject(btn);
```

You could encapsulate this logic in some methods for centralizing the code generation

Comment: how would you do it in jQuery?

Comment: var form = $('<form>').attr('id', 'formId').attr('class', 'formClass');
var btn = $('<input>').attr('type', 'button');

form.append(btn);

Hope it helps. Cumps.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a project that i created table tr and td using javascript :

objTR = document.createElement("TR");
objTR.setAttribute("id", "factor_row_" + id);

objTD = document.createElement("TD");
objDIV = document.createElement("DIV"); 
objDIV.setAttribute("id", "title_" + id);
objDIV.innerHTML = title;
objTD.appendChild(objDIV);
objTR.appendChild(objTD);

I think appendChild will work for you. You must just create your form element and it's attributes and then append it to it's parent. Hope it helps you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try as well a templating engine like [PURE](http://beebole.com/pure)
Define the HTML's and then you render them based on a JSON data.